# How to send JSON as a string into POST method

Tags: python, json

I want to send a JSON data as a string in POST method.
My Json input file contains:

```
{
    "data1":0
    "data2":"JSON"
    "data3": 78
}
```

I have a WEB-APP API in that the data should be in the following format

```
{"data0":"0","data2":"JSON", "data3":"78"}
```

I just store these value into a variable called `payload` using `json.dump("file name")`.

When parse this payload in to a POST function `server.action(path,payload)`.

I am getting an error the input is unhashable value.
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: do `json_data = str(your_dict)` and you're good.

Comment: No, you are not good. This will usually return avstring with single quotation marks which are not allowed in JSON. Use `json.dumps(your_dict)` instead.